# Need To Deregister Scripts Via Functions.Php

Tags: jquery

Well, I am a little disappointed how difficult Wordpress it makes to deregister scripts.

First, I got a list of all handles, so I looked it up and the handle was jquery-migrate

I then added this to my functions.php

```
wp_dequeue_script('jquery-migrate');
```

Also this

```
wp_dequeue_script('jquery');
```

It does nothing, although the scripts are properly registered.

What's up with the version strings, I can think of no reasons why they are still including those, should be removed in the next WP version asap, they only prevent caches from properly caching it in some cases and are annoying.

Any input on how to "properly" deregister scripts is appreciated.

Comment: what action and priority have you hooked these to? are there other scripts declaring jquery as dependency?

Comment: They are registered by 3rd-party plugins such as Nextgen Gallery and similar

Comment: I mean what action and priority are you trying to dequeue them on? and what priority have they been originally enqueued with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok the following does work now, I think it was a caching issue and I forgot to add the correct priorities

Using the priorities now it definitely works and I also managed to de-register Buddypress scripts

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'de_script', 100 );

function de_script() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
     wp_dequeue_script( 'bp-legacy-js' );
    wp_deregister_script( 'bp-legacy-js' );

}
```

Comment: bp-legacy-js => is the handle for the buddypress